# How to correctly initialise pointers within class function?

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

I am using a array of pointer's declared within a class to point to another array. When a pointer array element is initialised to a value within main that value is also carried to the array element it is pointing to. The following code show this and it works fine. However if I initialise the pointer within the init class function I get a segfault. Also if I try to access an element from the pointer array not initialised in main I also get a segfault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class testclass {
public:
    double  *Wgt;
    double* *LWgt;

    void init() {
        Wgt = new double[26];
        LWgt = new double*[26];

        //segfault from here
        *LWgt[5] = 22.34543; 
    }
};

int main() {

    testclass *node;
    node = new testclass[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        node[i].init();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {               //init_nconn here
        node[i].LWgt[23] = &node[i + 5].Wgt[12];
    }

    node[6].Wgt[12] = 50.6987;
    node[8].Wgt[12] = 0.999923;

    cout << *node[1].LWgt[23] << *node[3].LWgt[23] << "--\n";

    //No segfault
    *node[1].LWgt[23] = 33.234;

    cout << node[6].Wgt[12] << "---\n";
    //No segfault here
    cout << *node[1].LWgt[23] << "---\n";

    //Segfault from here
    cout << *node[3].LWgt[5] << "---\n";
}
```

Is there a way to initialise the pointer array within a class function without leading to a segfault?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: How do you do that I just used ctrl k.

Comment: Have you heard of constructors? Where are you learning this stuff from?

Comment: Yes I know about constructor and destructor but I dont normally use them. Would this make it work?

Comment: The line

    `LWgt = new double*[26];`

allocates 26 elements each of type pointer-to-double.  None of those elements point to anything.

Comment: I also cannot initialise each object with a constructor or see how to with an array of objects so I just use init().

Comment: Yes but if I try and initialise it in init() I get a segfault.

Comment: Any suggestions on the correct way of doing this though?

Comment: There is nothing incongruent with the following http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because none of the pointers stored inside `LWgt` actually point to anything valid yet. Remember that a pointer will be initialized by the runtime with some random value that may or may not be a valid address. When you try to stuff a value inside an invalid address you're going to get an error.

You need to initialize the pointers inside `LWgt` to point to some actual `double` memory locations before you can assign any values to them:

```
void init() {
    Wgt = new double[26];
    LWgt = new double*[26];

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        LWgt[i] = new double;

    //segfault from here
    *LWgt[5] = 22.34543; 
}
```

As a side note, this kind of initialization is probably best done inside a constructor for your class rather than a special initialization function. The point of constructors is that they always run automatically when the class is instantiated. You don't have to worry about remembering to call an init function right after you create the object.

Comment: Brilliant thanks for that its so obvious now that I think about it - I need to treat the pointer array as an array like any other. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

```
    LWgt = new double*[26];
```

allocates memory for 26 `double*` but does not allocate memory for the pointers themselves.

The line

```
    *LWgt[5] = 22.34543;
```

causes undefined behavior since memory hasn't been allocated for any of the elements of `LWgt`.

In order to be able to use that, you have to allocate memory for `LWgt[5]` first.

```
LWgt[5] = new double[<SOME_SIZE>];  // Allocate an array
```

or

```
LWgt[5] = new double; // Allocate just one element.
```

Answer (score 0):

Lwgt is an array of pointers to double.  You'd have to allocate each element in the array or remove the ** in the declaration.